# Rails Rake Task Email Notifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, actionmailer, rake-task

I'm new to writing Rails rake tasks.  I want to write a rake task that looks for calls that are within 30.minutes of being due and executing a mailer.  Below is the code I would use out of the controller, how can I adapt this to my rake task?

```
@call = Call.find(params[:id])
if Time.zone.now < @call.transfer_date + 30.minutes
   @call.units.each do |unit|
      CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.incharge, @call).deliver
      CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.attendant, @call).deliver
   end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :send_due_emails do
  desc "" #task describtion
  task :send_due_emails_task => :environment do
     send_emails
  end

  def send_emails
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    if Time.zone.now < @call.transfer_date + 30.minutes
      @call.units.each do |unit|
         CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.incharge, @call).deliver
         CallMailer.cancel_call(unit.attendant, @call).deliver
      end
    end
  end
end
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

Comment: I ran rake send_due_emails:send_due_emails_task and got this back: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object should I not be using instance variables?

Comment: Oh yes.  params is not available in the rake task.